# Should BST remove method remove a node's subtree aswell?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, removeall

So I got an assignment of creating a BST in Java and so far it has all went well. However I got a question about the remove method. As I have implemented, if I remove node X, all of node X's subtrees will also be deleted. And I just wondered if this is a common implementation, or should I rearrange the nodes if I delete one? I am also to make a AVL tree out of this class, so I will need a trinodeRestructering method. I guess This would need some modification aswell if I go in and deletenodes?

Thiis is how my remove method works:

```
    private TreeNode remove(TreeNode currN, int dataToRemove) {
    if (dataToRemove < currN.getData()) {
        if (currN.getLeft() != null) {
            if (currN.getLeft().getData() == dataToRemove) {
                currN.setLeft(null);
            } else {
                remove(currN.getLeft(), dataToRemove);
            }
        }
    } else if (dataToRemove > currN.getData()) {
        if (currN.getRight() != null) {
            if (currN.getRight().getData() == dataToRemove) {
                currN.setRight(null);
            } else {
                remove(currN.getRight(), dataToRemove);
            }
        }
    }
    return currN;
}


//visual representation

             /--------85
       /--------25
 /--------20
10
********************************************************************


*******removed 20******
10
*******************************************************************
```

Added tree for post:

```
             /--------85
       /--------25
             \--------24
 /--------20
       |     /--------13
       \--------12
       |     \--------11
10(root)
```

Here is some swapping I tried, it looks like really crappy, hard to read code:

```
if (dataToRemove < currN.getData()) {
        if (currN.getLeft() != null) {
            if (currN.getLeft().getData() == dataToRemove) {

                //Om inga barn, sätt noden till null.
                if(currN.getLeft().getLeft() == null && currN.getLeft().getRight() == null){
                    currN.setLeft(null); 
                }//Om noden enbart har höger barn
                else if(currN.getLeft().getLeft() == null){
                    TreeNode old = currN.getLeft().getRight();// Gamla höger
                    currN.setLeft(currN.getLeft().getLeft()); //
                    currN.getLeft().getRight().setRight((old)); // 
                }//Om noden enbart har vänster barn.
                else if(currN.getLeft().getRight() == null){
                    TreeNode old = currN.getLeft().getRight();// Gamla vänster
                    currN.setLeft(currN.getLeft().getLeft()); //
                    currN.getLeft().getLeft().setRight((old)); // 
                }//om två barn
                else{
                    TreeNode oldRight = currN.getLeft().getRight();// null
                    currN.setLeft(currN.getLeft().getLeft()); //sätt current left till 11
                    currN.getLeft().setRight((oldRight)); // current left, right till 13
                }
            } else {
                remove(currN.getLeft(), dataToRemove);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can, if your application requires this behaviour, but it is not usual. The fact that it's a "tree" is typically irrelevant: you're just storing "some" values in "some" data structure. Java's `TreeSet` is a binary search tree; this doesn't remove children when you remove an element, and it would be a PITA if it did, because you can't actually see the structure of the tree to know which elements would be removed a priori.

Answer (score 0):

yeah there is a known implementation for that , when you want to delete node in the binary search tree you swap it with the right most leaf of its left subtree, or the left most leaf of its right subtree then delete that leaf.

For the AVL you will have to keep track in you recursive operations of the balance condition , whenever that balance condition is violated you will need to do some kind of rotation depending on the structure of this violation , if you do some research you will find a decent amount of resources explaining the exact algorithms for this.

Comment: Ok, so what happends if I have the tree in the updated post and I want to remove node "25"? Should I Just replace it with either 85 or 24? Does it matter which?